# Live Stream Directly to Computer

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm a student currently working with a Matrice 100 for a project. I know that currently you can stream to YouTube/Facebook from the mobile app, but is there any way to get the stream directly to computer? I noticed that there was a mini hdmi port on the controller, could you plug a cable into that and a computer to access the stream?

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave this as a comment instead of an answer but I don't have enough reputation.

Do you have an HDMI cable on hand? You could try plugging one end into the hand controller and the other into a laptop.

Also, DJI has a [ground control application for the PC](http://www.dji.com/pc-ground-station) (although I don't think they are continuing support for it) that can be used with a [bluetooth radio](http://www.dji.com/2-4g-bluetooth-datalink?site=brandsite&from=insite_search) to communicate with and receive video from the aircraft. The application is free to download from the DJI website.